# Read the content of the file A and match with another file Example.html in given folder and rename the it with Example.html

Tags: python, html, file

I have the folder A and Folder B and  want to compare the file content in folder A with Folder B files .If the topictitle1 matches rename it with matching file name which is in Folder B.I have the output folder which I created manually to dump the renamed files

Folder A
01.html
02.html
03.html

Folder B
Test1.html
Test2.html
Test3.html

### 01.html and Test3.html File content common  lines [Need to rename 01.html as Test3.html in output folder]

First line

second line

### 02.html and Test2.html [Need to rename 02.html as Test2.html in output folder]

First line2

second line 2

### 03.html and Test1.html [Need to rename 01.html as Test1.html in output folder]

First line3

Second Line3

Now comparing two files and copy the file to output folder

```
import os
import shutil
hosts_filename = 'folderA/01.html'
logs_filename = 'folderB/Test3.html'
with open(hosts_filename, 'r') as f:
 hosts = f.read()
 hostSoup = BeautifulSoup(hosts , 'lxml')
 hostSoupS=hostSoup.select('h1.topictitle1')
 #print (hostSoupS)

with open(logs_filename, 'r') as f:
 lines = f.read()
 lineSoup = BeautifulSoup(lines , 'lxml')
 lineSoupS=lineSoup.select('h1.topictitle1')
 #print(lineSoupS)

for line in lineSoupS :
    for host in hostSoupS :
        if host == line:
            dest = shutil.copy(hosts_filename, "output/given_name.html")
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. You wrote "I have the folder A and Folder B and want to compare the file content in folder A with Folder B" Okay, but just after that you wrote "rename it with correct name". So depending what is inside a file you want to change the filename? What are the grounds to rename a file?